# Django Celery Beat Import/KeyError Issue

Tags: django, celery

I am using Django 1.6 with Celery. I have this task that I have running as a schedule. Everything looks correct, but I get this import error when the Celery(beat) runs:

```
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': [], 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'bot_data.tasks.get_unanswered_threads', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': '6143f259-721b-4984-99ae-790c00633271'} (233b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'bot_data.tasks.get_unanswered_threads'
```

base.py:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'get-unanswered-threads--every-15-seconds': {
        'task': 'bot_data.tasks.get_unanswered_threads',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=15),
        'args': ()
    },
}
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

from bot_data/get_unanswered_threads:

```
@task()
def get_unanswered_threads():
    slug = 'forums/threads/unanswered.json?PageSize=100'
    thread_batch = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had bot_data.tasks.get_unanswered_threads incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc's](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator) specifies the the annotation as `@shared_task` instead of `@task`.